# Using delegates, anonymous(lambda) functions, and function pointers

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, anonymous-function

I have read a little about anonymous(lambda) functions and delegates.  I believe that I a have am dealing with a situation where a section of my function could/should utilize them.  I am not sure if my assumptions is correct.

Current code:

```
fDoSave(fGetSqlCheckEmpJob(), fGetSqlUpdateEmpJob(), fGetSqlInsertEmpJob());
fDoSave(fGetSqlCheckEmpPayrl(), fGetSqlUpdateEmpPayrl(), fGetSqlInsertEmpPayrl());
fDoSave(fGetSqlCheckEEO(), fGetSqlUpdateEEO(), fGetSqlInsertEEO());
fDoSave(fGetSqlCheckEmpPhone(), fGetSqlUpdateEmpPhone(), fGetSqlInsertEmpPhone());
```

`fGetSqlCheck...()` - returns a sql statement as a string that returns a count() of all the rows with a certain ID
`fGetSqlUpdate...()` returns a sql statement as a string that does an update.
`fGetSqlInsert...()` returns a sql statement as a string that does an insert.
`fDoSave()` does either an update or an insert depending on the value returned by `fGetCheck...()`

The fGetSql functions look like this:

```
private string fGetSql...()
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   //Create sql statement
   return sb.ToString();
}
```

The fDoSave functions looks like this:

```
private void fDoSave(string sSql_Check, string sSql_Update, sSql_Insert)
{
   OracleDataReader dr = ERPDB.sqlGetDataReader(sSql_Check);
   while (dr.Read())
   {
        if(fCheckIfRecrodExists(dr) > 0) //if fGetSqlCheck...() found a row with a specific ID
            //do update using sSql_Update
        else
            //do insert using sSql_Insert
    }
}
```

Can this be re-written using either lambda functions or delegates, and should it?  How should it be re-written?

Comment: What are all those methods?

Comment: If you down vote a question it would be common courtesy (and very helpful) to explain why and how you think the question should be changed.

Comment: I can't because your question doesn't mean anything to me.

Comment: We need to see what each method does, to make any kind of judgements. As the code is not really clear on what it does. Also you might consider changing your coding style, if that is your code.

Comment: @I4V What about "Can this be re-written using either lambda functions or delegates, and should it? How should it be re-written?" do you find challenging to understand?

Comment: @AndréSnedeHansen I would post an example, but its a lot of code.

Comment: @Azzi No, it is a vague question. If you posted a simple, self-contained code and asked on it, maybe....

Comment: @AndréSnedeHansen "Also you might consider changing your coding style" could you please explain?

Comment: @Azzi - A replay to this is given in my Answer, and in it's attached comment section. ( for future readers )

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be in codereview.stackexchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is still vague, but I'll put it like this.

***Cases:***

**1: Reusable and "static"**
If you reuse the SQL Statements and they are somewhat static, put them in Properties. And consider better names.

**2: Reusable but "variable" though simple**
If you reuse the SQL Statements and they are variable but doesn't use much CPU, meaning they change by different states, and are very fast to create and build,  then let them be as they are.

**3: Reusable but "variable" and complex**
If you reuse the SQL Statements and they are variable but are very complex and requires alot of CPU power, put them in method, but call them as delegates, do not make them anonymous.

**4: Not-Reusable but "variable" and complex**
If you will never reuse the SQL Statements(which probably not ever be the case) and they are variable and very complex and requires alot of CPU power, put them in an anonymous function.

**In all cases**
Use better names.

**My suggestion**
I would prefer case 1 and 2, as the rest seems to be an overly complex solution to a problem that probably doesn't exist.
Also, I don't know your entire codebase, but I don't like that the object that is supposed to be saved isn't given to fDoSave().

I would have done it something like this:

```
// Also often called Upsert short for "Update or Insert"
public int Save(EmpObj employeeObj) 
{
     if(CheckIfEmployeeExists(employeeObj))
     {
         return Update(employeeObj); // returns rows affected
     }
     else
     {
         return Insert(employeeObj); // Returns new Id of the employee.
     }
}

// Other methods, where the select, update and insert statements lies 
or gets called    and build
public bool CheckIfEmployeeExists(employeeObj) // Check If Employee Exists
public int Update(employeeObj); // Updates the employee
public int Insert(employeeObj); // Inserts the employee
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer and giving constructive comments.  Regarding naming conventions.  My company has a naming convention I have to follow.  Plus I think fGetSqlInsertEmpPayrl is pretty descriptive.  'f' for function, 'GetSql' that it will return a sql statement, 'Insert' since it will be an insert statement, 'EmpPayrl' because that is the table it functions on.  Please let me know what is a better/your approach.

Comment: After you updated your answer I understand what you didn't like about the code.  I can't do that as it is not my code, its part of a large and old codebase.  Part of the project requirements is to minimize code changes. :)  The second part of your answer is a great suggestion but has nothing to do with my question.  I didn't ask "how to re-write my code like its not 1996" :)

Comment: First of all I don't like the hungarian style, but that's more religion than anything, other than that GetSql... looks like java getters, which might indicate you are not using C# to its full potential. Lastly, I wasn't entirely sure what your code did, and why it did it. fDoSave, why did that need 3 SQL statements? I didn't know until you explained further, but that is a structural issue rather than a naming convention problem.

Comment: @Azzi ofcourse, and I was kind of expecting that reply from you, which is also why it is just a suggestion, and has no real context with your original question.

Comment: @Azzi Great, I thought so, you could still have gone with properties, but in category 1 and 2, you can choose which ever you want, for different scenerios, but by using methods rather than properties ( which can solve the same problem) for variable statements, methods tells the future developer than it is a more complex procedure than just a preset value. - Also I'm glad I could help :)